# jquery callbacks being called multiple times

Tags: jquery, callback

When I use the fade/slide/animate functions in jQuery the callback gets called multiple times for each element the effect is applied to.  This is by design of course.  I just want to know when the last callback is called.

Here is what I came up with-  it fades out all the divs and displays an alert() when the last callback is fired.

```
$("div").fadeOut(1000, function ()
{
     if ($("div").index($(this)) == $("div").length-1)
          alert("this is the final callback");
});
```

Is there a simpler way to check which callback is the last one or is this the only way to do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That would produce the alert when the fadeOut on the last element was called. That would not necessarily be the last fadeOut.

```
var numDivs = $('div').length;
$('div').fadeOut(1000, function() {
  if( --numDivs > 0 ) return;
  alert('this is the final fadeout to complete');
});
```

Check it out on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53GZS/)

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you're saying.  Good call!

Comment: yep, good thinking. I like the other solutions too but this one 100% correct.

Comment: Apologies - should be 'numDivs' inside the function.

Comment: Shouldn't it actually be if( numDivs-- > 1 ) return;

Comment: A bit hacking for my taste, but it works, and I can't think of anything better.

Comment: (Invalid Edit by Anonymous) You need the subtraction to the left of the numDivs condition (--numDivs) otherwise the alert will never get called (I've tested this!)

Comment: yup that was the exact problem with mine too!! Plus one it is :)

Answer (score 48):

Try taking a look at [the jQuery documentation for .promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)

This should work:

```
$('div').fadeOut(1000).promise().done(function() {
   alert('all done');
});
```

As usualy, the jQuery documentation on this is really vague. But I'm not sure I could do

Comment: The only issue with this method is that it waits until all calls have finished. so if you have a button that activates that function and click it multiple times it won't fire after it finishes the animation each time. it will fade out several times and then call all the promise functions after that.  So in some circumstances it isn't the best solution.

Comment: You may also want to check out [jQuery's .finish()](http://api.jquery.com/?s=finish%28%29) method, which may alleviate the multiple click problems mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div:not(:last)").fadeOut(1000);
$("div:last").fadeOut(1000, function() {
    alert("Hey!");
});
```