# jquery animation callback called once instead of for each element

Tags: jquery, callback

```
$($('div').children()).animate({opacity:"0"},
                        function(){
                                $(this).remove();
                                $('div').append('new content');
                            }
                        );
```

New content is getting doubled every time, how would I go about making the callback function only fire once instead of for each child?

Comment: FYI, you don't have to pass `$('div').children()` to jQuery again, just chain the call: `$('div').children().animate(...)`.

Comment: More duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/909526/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/8790752/218196

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.promise`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) along with `.done`:

From the documentation:

> The `.promise()` method returns a dynamically generated Promise that is resolved once all actions of a certain type bound to the collection, queued or not, have ended.
>
> By default, type is "fx", which means the returned Promise is resolved when all animations of the selected elements have completed.

So the usage would be:

```
$(myElements).animate(...).promise().done(function() {
    // called only when _all_ of the animations on
    // "myElements" elements have completed
});
```

Comment: It's a duplicate though `:-/`

Comment: So it is, although the accepted answer on the first question you mentioned is over the top for this example.

Comment: That's why I pointed out to use the other answer. All the questions I found so far mention `.promise().done` at some point. Just saying. We don't need more of those IMO.

Comment: very few of them have it as the accepted answer, unfortunately :(