# why does this function behave like a loop?

Tags: jquery, function, loops, callback, increment

The function that triggers when the slideUp is complete in this example, seems to act like a loop because the alert goes off twice here. The variable aaa is set to 3 earlier in my script:

```
$("ul.level" + aaa).slideUp(
    function() {
        aaa --;
        alert (aaa);
    }
);
```

Why is this?

Comment: slideUp() callback  is called for each matched element

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery callbacks being called multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909526/jquery-callbacks-being-called-multiple-times)

Answer (score 3):

If you want slideUp() callback to be called only once for all set, use a promise:

```
$("ul.level" + aaa).slideUp().promise()
.done(function () {
    aaa--;
    alert(aaa);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, thats precicely what I wanted in the first place! :D

Answer (score 1):

Because `$("ul.level" + 2)` will be called when aaa is decremented.